# How to Convert a time into its time format

Tags: java, time, format

My input is time (String variable) for example `11:03` and I need to get output as its format which is `HH:MM`. Please help.

I tried the below. But this only compares if the time is equal. I need to know if the format also matches.

```
if (savedtime.compareTo(enteredtime)==0)
{
info(" The entered time format " + splitArr[i] + " matches with the saved time " + savedtime);
}
```

Comment: What language would you like to use?

Comment: It'd be helpful if you mentioned WHICH LANGUAGE you're using. Perhaps you're translating english->german, in which case this isn't a programming question at all.

Comment: Isn't the input and output format same?

Comment: @AbhinavRanjan Are asking if input and output formats are the same across various programming languages? No, formats vary across programming languages and vary across various libraries used within those languages.

Comment: Here i was pointing to the fact that his example input which is a string is 11:05 and desired output is hh:mm which will be 11:05.

Comment: 0down voteaccept 



Thanks for the comments. The language is Java. And just to clarify my input is for example 11:30 and I need to get an ouput as its time format which is HH:MM. I need to compare the time format from two different source. I have looked everywhere but they only give answer for the other way conversion from a time format to a time.

Thanks

Comment: @user3123534: 11:30 *is already* in the format HH:MM. I recommend you go back and rewrite the question.

Comment: @JonathanWood I need my java code to read 11:30 and print out the format which is HH:MM.

Answer (score 0):

If the language is Java then have a look at DateFormat where you can assign your specified pattern.

In other languages there are similar possibilities.

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-M-yyyy hh:mm:ss");
String dateInString = "31-08-1982 10:20:56";
Date date = sdf.parse(dateInString);
System.out.println(date); //Tue Aug 31 10:20:56 SGT 1982
```

Example Taken from here: http://www.mkyong.com/java/java-date-and-calendar-examples/

Answer (score 0):

If programming in Java, and using [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/), see [the doc on formatting](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/key_format.html). Then search StackOverflow for many similar questions already answered.